# Change string mm/dd/yyyy format date to datetime dd/mm/yyyy format date

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, datetimepicker, datetime-format

I have used string in accepting the parameter in the controller for dates.

```
public ActionResult Export(string fromDate, string toDate)
{
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(fromDates))
         DateTime dDate = DateTime.Parse(fromDates);
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(toDates))
         DateTime dDate = DateTime.Parse(toDates);
}
```

Convert from `"03/30/2018" to 30/03/2018 12:00:00 AM`

Please help me. Thanks.

Comment: How do you know the date format of input values will always be `MM/dd/yyyy`? Does it depend on the client computer's settings?

Comment: What makes you think `DateTime` values have a specific format at all? They are stored in a binary format that's not human readable, and only shown any other way after converting to a string, which is a different type completely. Now you can interpret (parse) an aa/bb/yyyy string as a DateTime in that that swaps the a and b values for day and month in different ways, but that's while it's still a string. Once you parse it to a DateTime, that source string value is irrelevant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `DateTime.ParseExact` with `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture`:

```
DateTime fromDateDt = DateTime.ParseExact( fromDate, "MM/dd/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture );
DateTime toDateDt   = DateTime.ParseExact( toDate  , "MM/dd/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture );
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `DateTme.ParseExact` you can try with the below code :

```
DateTime ConvertedVal = DateTime.ParseExact("03/30/2018", "MM/dd/yyyy", null);
```

Sample Demo
https://dotnetfiddle.net/fuc3PN